# How to buffer (high input impedance required) a differential signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, differential, input-impedance, differential-amplifier

I'm wanting a to increase the input impedance to a differential ADC. The ADC spec states that it can't handle a negative voltage lower than -100mV the ADC's supply can handle ~5V (this is a ATtiny1617)

I assume this means that the differential input works as follows into the IN+ and IN- pins of the ADC?
IN+ = 0v & IN- = 0-5v, this would be the negative range of the ADC
IN+ = 0-5v & IN- = 0v, this would be the positive range of the ADC

Assuming the above is correct. I need to buffer the input to increase the input impedance.

I've simulated the following circuit and it works fine, however I don't want R2 & R3 on the input as this reduced the input impedance, but if I remove these the simulation doesn't work.

The simulation also shows that X1-out & X2-inn swing negative. How should this be resolved?

[image]

[image]

Below with R2 & R3 removed

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why is 10Mohm not good enough for you? Also, if you're biasing your input signals at 0V, why don't you AC couple your inputs?

Comment: First things first- it is necessary to ensure that both inputs remain within the common-mode input range of the op-amp (in the case of the MCP6001, approximately within the supply voltage rails). How best to do that depends on where the voltage is coming from. For example, you could ground one side of the source and get GΩ input Z, but then you wouldn't need a differential amplifier.

Comment: @ErnestoG the sensor this will interface is very high impedance. Its a PH sensor.

Comment: @John you should add that info in your question. Source impedance is a very important piece of information in any amplifier design.

Comment: related: [Differential ADC input buffer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121288/differential-adc-input-buffer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an INA or INstrument Amp IC to create the Gohm differential interface with a common external pair of gain resistors that are well matched and use that common mode signal inverted to feed back to the solution like “Right Leg Drive” **RLD** does for ECG/EKG or EEG circuits use to suppress interference then drive the ADC with a differential amp well-designed or use STP cable single-ended. All must be somehow DC biased to the middle of the CM range.  I suggest you consider those solutions but bypass the C coupling.

Proximity to sensor is important as well as choice of “ground” = 0V for DC high impedance sensor and EMI for AC reduction just like in EEG microvolt 1 Hz signals. **This requires a precise level shift from 0V = null on input to 2.5V = null on ADC.** which is added to the INA as a Vref or the next stage.

The EEG prefilters are also useful for you to suppress line-induced Efield voltages and AM radio RF.